# How do I set different Serializer for list and detail view with Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

How do I set a different Serializer for list and detail view while using  `viewsets.ModelViewSet` and `HyperlinkedSerializer`?

I see how to do it with `viewsets.ViewSet` by defining `list` and `retrive`, ([here's an example](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets#example)) but I don't know how to elegantly adapt it to `viewsets.ModelViewSet`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22616973/django-rest-framework-use-different-serializers-in-the-same-modelviewset

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I've adapted an answer from "[Django rest framework, use different serializers in the same ModelViewSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22616973/django-rest-framework-use-different-serializers-in-the-same-modelviewset)" that serves me very well, and I hope you'll find useful:

```
class MyModelViewSet(viewsets.MyModelViewSet):

    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MyModelListSerializer
    detail_serializer_class = MyModelDetailSerializer

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action == 'retrieve':
            if hasattr(self, 'detail_serializer_class'):
                return self.detail_serializer_class

        return super(MyModelViewSet, self).get_serializer_class()
```

In this case, you're just specifying your two serializers and using the one depending on the action. However, this can be made more general (for all actions) as follows:

```
class MyModelViewSet(viewsets.MyModelViewSet):

    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer

    action_serializers = {
        'retrieve': MyModelDetailSerializer,
        'list': MyModelListSerializer,
        'create': MyModelCreateSerializer
    }

    def get_serializer_class(self):

        if hasattr(self, 'action_serializers'):
            return self.action_serializers.get(self.action, self.serializer_class)

        return super(MyModelViewSet, self).get_serializer_class()
```

Comment: How is a API request for list different from detail?

Comment: It works perfectly for my use case as well. Could you explain a little bit about the second method?

Answer (score 1):

Viewsets extend the class GenericAPIView, so you can use [this part of the documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views#genericapiview) to solve your problem. Basically, what you need is to override *get_serializer_class* and to return a different serializer based on your request.

Answer (score 0):

I've created this small package for this job. [drf_custom_viewsets](https://github.com/Darwesh27/drf-custom-viewsets).

It has `CustomSerializerViewSet`, which inherits from `ModelViewSet`, which lets you set different serializers for different actions.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2021, I will do it differently, a better and more generic way around is doing something like this:

```
class PlayersListViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Player.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PlayersListSerializer
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post']
    pagination_class = None
    filter_backends = [filters.OrderingFilter]
    ordering_fields = ['name']

    serializer_class_by_action = {
        'retrieve': PlayersDetailSerializer,
        'list': PlayersListSerializer,
    }

    def get_serializer_class(self):

        if hasattr(self, 'serializer_class_by_action'):
            return self.serializer_class_by_action.get(self.action, self.serializer_class)

        return super(MyModelViewSet, self).get_serializer_class()

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Player.objects.all()
        team_id = self.request.query_params.get('team', None)

        if team_id:
            try:
                queryset = queryset.filter(team=team_id)
            except ValueError:
                raise exceptions.ParseError()
        return queryset
```

Here `action` is the method used by the serializer, `list` in case of `def list`, `retrieve` in case of `def retrieve` and so on..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @bbengfort, I've provided a simple solution without the need to create a new `ViewSet`.

### Different Serializer Per Action In the ViewSet in Django

##### TL;DR

In the following code, we are overriding `get_serializer_class` based on [Django  documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#get_serializer_classself) and we're specifying different serializers per action if it's needed:

##### Views.py

```
class TestAPIView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = TestAPISerializer

    serializer_class_by_action = {
        'update_me': UpdateMeSerializer,
    }

    def get_serializer_class(self):

        if hasattr(self, 'serializer_class_by_action'):
            return self.serializer_class_by_action.get(self.action, self.serializer_class)

        return self.serializer_class

    @action(detail=True, methods=['patch'], url_name='Update Me', url_path='updateme')
    def update_me(self, request, pk=None):
        # Write your own logic
        return Response("OK")
```

##### Serializers.py

```
class UpdateMeSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    count = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_null=True, default=10)
    class Meta:
        fields = ['count']
```