# DRF show different fields on 'list' and 'get_object'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am using viewsets like this:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """Viewset for model User."""

    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

and my serializer has following fields:

```
fields = ('id', 'url', 'username', 'first_name', 'middle_name', 'last_name', 'role',
          'get_role_display', 'is_authenticated', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser', )
```

When I access the api to list all users with this url `/api/user/`, it returns this json_data:

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user/1/",
    "username": "admin",
    "first_name": "",
    "middle_name": null,
    "last_name": "",
    "role": "A",
    "get_role_display": "Admin",
    "is_authenticated": true,
    "is_staff": true,
    "is_superuser": true
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user/2/",
    "username": "7004104463",
    "first_name": "Vaibhav",
    "middle_name": "Bold",
    "last_name": "Vishal",
    "role": "S",
    "get_role_display": "Student",
    "is_authenticated": true,
    "is_staff": false,
    "is_superuser": false
}
]
```

But what I am trying to do is returns only a few fields on list, say only `'id', 'username', 'url',` but on requests where a single object is requested like this `/api/user/1/` I want to return all fields. I want to avoid using two different rest_framework views. I want a single viewset and serializer to achieve this. Is there any way to make it happen?
I am using React on frontend and I want to avoid fetching unnecessary data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only way that I know of is to overwrite the [`get_serializer_class`-Method](http://www.cdrf.co/3.7/rest_framework.viewsets/ModelViewSet.html#get_serializer_class) and return a different `Serializer` based on the current request.

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    ....
    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action == 'retrieve':
            return UserDetailSerializerClass
        return UserListSerializerClass
```

There is also a [pypi package](https://github.com/Darwesh27/drf-custom-viewsets)

Credits: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22755648/7774036 & https://stackoverflow.com/a/30670569/7774036

Comment: Thanks, I will use try this tomorrow, meanwhile I will also try to find some way to make this work with just one seriailzer.

Comment: Serializers aren't designed to work the way you want, but I'm sure there is a way to hack it in.   Its code, there always is, but I wouldn't recommend it.  Learn how to use >1, and maybe use the pypi package to make it easier (i wrote my own version).

Comment: I figure out a few different solutions like popping fields in __init__ of serializer depending on view's action. Those made the code a little shorter but more complicated. So I think using different serializer class is the best option as suggested by you.