# django-rest-framework multiple serializers in the same request

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, multi-table-inheritance

I know there's something similar answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22616973/django-rest-framework-use-different-serializers-in-the-same-modelviewset), but my question is not the same. I'm using multi-table inheritance to model 2 different types of entities, and both of them can create posts. My problem is when trying to create a view that shows all the posts together.

So I have my Entity model, and then my ETypeA and ETypeB models, which look like this:

```
class Entity(models.Model):
    pass

class ETypeA(Entity):
    # Here are some attributes
    pass

class ETypeB(Entity):
    # Here are some attributes
    pass
```

As you can see, the Entity model it's just for having a common primary key between ETypeA and ETypeB. The reason for this is to have just one common Post model, like this:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    transmitter = models.ForeignKey(Entity, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=False, blank=False)
```

The problem now is that when I create a view to show the posts I get only the id of the transmitter but I need the whole information. The way of doing it in SQL should be joining the results with ETypeA, then with ETypeB and make a union between the results (keeping some fields as nulls). Then I should be capable of sorting them by date. How can I do that with DRF views and serializers?

Comment: What does your serializer look like?

Comment: It is part of the problem, I suppose I should define a serializer with a mix of the two models, but I don't know how to do it right, yet.