# DRF create writable not model field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Is there any way to create serializer not model writable field from model two fields? Here is my Serializer

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    full_name = ?
    class Meta:
        model = users.models.User
        fields = (
            'phone_number',
            'email',
            'city',
            'full_name'
        )
```

I want to connect firts_name and last_name into full_name

Answer (score 2):

You can use `serializers.CharField()` with `write_only` attribute;

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    full_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=225, write_only=True,
                                      required=False, allow_null=True)
    class Meta:
        model = users.models.User
        fields = (
            'phone_number',
            'email',
            'city',
            'full_name'
        )
```

then you will be able to send json data like;

```
{
    "phone_number": "123456789",
    "email": "foo@bar.com",
    "city": "Foo",
    "full_name": "My Full Name"
}
```

and for getting that value after `serializer.is_valid()` method;

```
full_name = serializer.validated_data.get('full_name', '')
# full_name --> My Full Name
```

Comment: In this case, it will not response full_name value on the get request.

Comment: Then, I prefer you to use different serializers based on action. [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22922156/10170918)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `SerializerMethodField` to construct the **full_name** from **first_name** + **last_name**:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    full_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = users.models.User
        fields = (
            'phone_number',
            'email',
            'city',
            'full_name'
        )

    def get_full_name(self, instance):
        return "{} {}".format(instance.first_name, instance.last_name)
```

Comment: How can you make it writable? Where would you put its value if there is not **full_name** field in the model?