# Django REST Framework, different serializers in same GenericView

Tags: python, django, serialization

I have a question regarding using only 1 view or end-point to make multiple requests. We have a url defined as

```py
path('ap/', APIndex.as_view())
```

where we'd like to both get all our AP models as well as create a new one.

We have checked the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22616973/django-rest-framework-use-different-serializers-in-the-same-modelviewset),
mostly the answer where Mohammad Masoumi mentioned the `get_serializer_class` method and the use of generic views.

This has not worked however as we get the following error message when doing a simple GET request on the above URL.

```
AttributeError at /ap/
'APIndex' object has no attribute 'action'
```

This occurs in our views_ap.py file in the `get_serializer_class` method. I have not been able neither to print the self to see what object I had in there.

You'll find below our `views_ap.py` and `serializers_ap.py`:

`views_ap.py`:

```py
from rest_framework import generics
from ..models.model_ap import AP
from ..serializers.serializers_ap import *
from ..serializers.serializers_user import *

class APIndex(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
   """List all ap, or create a new ap."""

   # serializer_classes = {
   #     'get': APIndexSerializer,
   #     'post': UserIDSerializer,
   #     # ... other actions
   # }
   queryset = AP.objects.all().order_by('id')

   # mapping serializer into the action
   serializer_classes = {
       'list': APIndexSerializer,
       'create': APCreateSerializer
   }

   default_serializer_class = APIndexSerializer # Default serializer

   def get_serializer_class(self):
       print(self)
       return self.serializer_classes.get(self.action, self.default_serializer_class)
```

`serializers_ap.py`:

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from ..models.model_ap import AP
from .serializers_user import *


class APIndexSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserIndexSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = AP
        fields = [
            'id',
            'user',
            'name'
        ]

    def to_representation(self, obj):
        self.fields['user'] = UserIndexSerializer()
        return super(APIndexSerializer, self).to_representation(obj)

class APCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # user = UserIDSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = AP
        fields = [
            'user',
            'name'
        ]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        ap = AP.objects.create(**validated_data)
        return ap
```

Being new to Django I actually have a few questions, to better understand it:

- Is it possible to detect the request type using Generic views (GET,
  POST etc.)?
- If yes, then how to do so?
- I am correct in understanding that the `self` object in the
  `get_serializer_class` method actually is the request?

Thanks!