# How to make Django Rest Framework Serializers to work different with GET and POST request

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

Actually, I have am creating the API for Bookmark manager, where I will be having CRUD operations on Bookmark, Collection and Tags

Here I am using the `BookmarkSerializer` for serialization,

```
class BookmarkSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Bookmark
        fields = "__all__"
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
      tags_data = validated_data.pop('tags', []) 
      bookmark = Bookmark.objects.create(**validated_data)

      for tag_data in tags_data:
            bookmark.tags.add(tag_data)
      
      return bookmark
```

and Bookmark model is like

```
class Bookmark(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    url = models.URLField()
    thumbnail_url = models.URLField(blank=True, default="https://site.image.jpg")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=512, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    note = models.TextField(blank=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField("Tag", blank=True)
    is_favorite = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    collection = models.ForeignKey("Collection", on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

My requirement is that, when `GET` request comes in I will return all information, and when `POST` request comes in I will create the new instance of `Bookmark` model. Here everything works well, but in the response the primary keys (`id`) of user, tags and collections are sent, which I don't want. I want it to be string representation.
Like

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "url": "https://www.flipkart.com/",
        "title": "Exiting website",
        "description": "",
        "note": "Shopping website",
        "is_favorite": false,
        "created_at": "2023-08-14T20:41:32.033584Z",
        "user": "john2000",
        "collection": "Shopping",
        "tags": [ "buy", "great_ui"]
    }
```

but result's are,

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "url": "https://www.flipkart.com/",
        "title": "Exiting website",
        "description": "",
        "note": "Shopping website",
        "is_favorite": false,
        "created_at": "2023-08-14T20:41:32.033584Z",
        "user": 3,
        "collection": 5,
        "tags": [ 2, 3]
    }
```

So, I want that type of string representation, without changing the `create` method because for other endpoints also I have `PATCH`, `PUT`, `POST` methods that need to be changed making more cumbersome. I just want data retrieval should be changed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django rest framework, use different serializers in the same ModelViewSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22616973/django-rest-framework-use-different-serializers-in-the-same-modelviewset)

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is actually create a separate serializers for each relation and add that in Bookmark serializer like this:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
       model = User

class CollectionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
       model = Collection

class TagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
       model = Tag

class BookmarkSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()
    collection = CollectionSerializer()
    tags = TagSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Bookmark
        fields = ["id", "url", "title", "description", "note",
                  "is_favorite", "created_at", "user", "collection", "tags"]
```